# How to Link to a page using index number for a dynamic page

Tags: php, mysql, dynamic, hyperlink, indexing

I have created a page from the database with the following codes:

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `inventory` where `prod_id` = 1"; // manipulate id ok 
$qry = mysql_query($sql);
$result=mysql_fetch_array($qry);

// this is code to display picture
echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $result['prod_pic'] ).'"/>'

?>
<br>

<?php
// this is to display info

    $qry = "SELECT * from inventory where prod_id = 1";
    $result = @mysql_query($qry);
    while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
        echo $row['prod_desc'];
    }
?>
```

Now my problem or question is how do I create a link to replace the id for prod_id, for example sample1 link contains prod_id number 1, how do i make a dynamic page so that when i press sample1 it would go to the page for product number 1 and so on for other links? 
I really hope i explained my question well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope that I understand the question but it should work if you replace prod_id = 1 with a parameter.

```
$qry = "SELECT * from inventory where prod_id = ".$prodID;
```

Then you create $postID from URL parameters ($_GET / URL Parsing).

exemple with http://yourdomain.com/sample?product=1

```
$prodID = your_escape_function($_GET['product']);
```

To avoid some security issues, escape your $prodID variable BEFORE execute your query on database.

---

Edit : To create your links, you select in your base every products.

```
$qry = "SELECT * from inventory where prod_id;
```

Then for each product, you create your URL, (i didn't use mysql_fetch for a while, the code may be wrong, but idea is good) :

```
$result = @mysql_query($qry);
while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    echo '<a href="http://yourdomain.com/sample?product='.$row['prod_id'].'">Link to product #'.$row['prod_id'].'</a>';
}
```

(It's really important especially in this case to care about security issues if you put site online/reachable, especially sql injections)

Good luck !

Comment: so how do i create a link for the parameters? i am really new to php and my thesis is really killing me. thank you for you help.